# commend a player in Counter-Strike 2 programmatically

Tags: c#, modding, steam, bot

I'm trying to Automate a Task which involves commending a player in a specific server (unofficial custom server), I looked into several open source project but all of them are deprecated and archived and no longer work.

I'm trying to achieve this in C# or Rust.

CSGO currently has no API or any "commands" to do this, but I've seen people doing this on several sites so it is possible.

Comment: "I've seen people doing this on several sites so it is possible" -- so get in touch with those mod authors, and ask them how it's done.

While modding questions are allowed here, you're far more likely to get an answer directly from an CS(GO) enthusiast site.

Comment: @Engineer 99% of them are paid products so I dont think they will share the "big secrets" with me, thats one of the reasons im doing this, I want to make it public and open source so everyone can use it)